# Access accdb MsysObjects permission

Tags: ms-access-2010, table-relationships

Hello to forum from a part time occasional user of MS Access 2010:

Trying to get permission to allow a third party application read MsysObjects which in turn will allow it to save a copy of the table relationship window in a form that will allow the layout to be recovered when it crashes (frequently - and is a known irritation/bug).

Have tried the method suggested in quote from this forum [HansUp] without success - including substiting this DAO line for the last ADO line following advice on a different forum:

dbEngine(0)(0).Execute strDdl, dbFailOnError

> Since your db is ACCDB format, you will be working as user Admin. You can confirm that point in the Immediate window. (Go there with Ctrl+g)
>
> `? CurrentUser()`
>
> `Admin`
>
> Since Admin doesn't have read (SELECT) permission on MSysObjects, execute a DDL statement to give Admin that permission.
>
> `strDdl = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"`
>
> CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl

Advice from yet another forum to import or export to fresh blank accdb gives no result as permissions are still not available.

All this is beyond my pay grade so any advice welcome.

Comment: User _Admin_ does have that right granted by default, so you might be fighting another issue.

Comment: Your comment conflicts with previous post on this forum.  By "HansUp", 82.5k, subject "Record cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'".  And you offer no possible "other issue".

Comment: User security was put to sleep at Access 2007 for the JET 4 format (mdb files) and does not exist for the accdb format, so since then only user Admin is active. As for that old question, I can't tell; the query posted there runs right away for me with Access 2016, listing all local table names, and it will do so for any version - just tested with Access 2.0(!).

Comment: Thank you Gustav:  All I have to go on is what was already on this forum and others.  I am trying to use a utility by Stephen Lebans - so it has provenance ..... but I do not have the understanding to get it to work and have been helped by a moderator on an Access forum.  I have tried to import the Lebans utility into a new blank accdb and have saved out as "mine".  Permissions issue removed but no functionality.  So will return to the Access forum to see what they say.  Regards - Paul

Comment: OK. Lebans' stuff is old by now, so be prepared for some challenges.

Comment: Ah !  So this begs the question ... is there a better way to save the relationship window to be able to restore it when MS Access throws a tantrum ?  (apart from a jpeg and tab delete of course - but so far that has taken less time than trying the programatic way )  Regards - Paul